# Failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable

Tags: codeigniter, ajaxform

when i try to upload files with ajax and CI4 I have this error on the console

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: "PassagerController/addInformation",
    method: "POST",
    data : new FormData(this),
    dataType:'json',
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
```

the controller:

```
 {
    $passager = new PassagerModel();
    $id = session()->get('telephone');
    $numcni = $this->request->getPost('numcni');
    $file = $this->request->getFile('rectocni');
    if ($file->isValid() && ! $file->hasMoved()) {
        $rectocni = $file->getRandomName();
        $file->move(base_url().'/public',$rectocni);
    }
```

then i allready put enctype=multipart/form-data

Comment: Share the error you are getting.

Comment: The error i get is allready on the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to open a file over HTTP and expect it to be written on a local path. Remove "base_url()" and replace it with a local path.

As you are looking to store the file under the "public" directory, you can update the code to -

```
if ($file->isValid() && ! $file->hasMoved()) {
    $rectocni = $file->getRandomName();
    $file->move(ROOTPATH.'public', $rectocni);
}
```

"ROOTPATH" is a constant that has the path to the project root directory.

It is not good practice to store the uploaded file in the "public" directory, instead, look to place it under a sub directory under "writable".